# How to observe method invocation in ViewModel?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I'm new to ReactiveCocoa. In my Swift ViewController, I'd like to observe/listen to the invocation of the following method in the RecipeSwipingViewModel:

```
func fillSwipingQueueWith(recipeSwipingCards: [RecipeSwipingCardVM]) { ... }
```

Unfortunately, I cannot get this to work, although I guess it is a pretty common use case. I tried several variations of this:

```
self.viewModel.rac_signalForSelector("fillSwipingQueueWith")...
self.viewModel.rac_signalForSelector("fillSwipingQueueWith:")...
self.viewModel.rac_signalForSelector(Selector("fillSwipingQueueWith:"))...
self.viewModel.rac_signalForSelector("fillSwipingQueueWith:", fromProtocol:NSProtocolFromString("RecipeSwipingViewModel")...
```

What am I missing? Is it actually possible to listen to the method invocation inside another object (without a protocol)? Help is highly appreciated.

Cheers, Gerardo

Answer (score 1):

`rac_signalForSelector` is implemented by Objective-C runtime features. To make it work in Swift, you must mark your method as `dynamic`:

```
dynamic func fillSwipingQueueWith(recipeSwipingCards: [RecipeSwipingCardVM])
```

Then a `rac_signalForSelector("fillSwipingQueueWith:")` signal should send corretly.

Note, this is impossible if the method is a pure Swift function (e.g. it takes a Swift struct argument) or if the class of the method doesn't inherit from NSObject. The Swift way of observing method invocation is making the signal explicit. For example:

```
class ViewModel {
    let (callSignal, callObserver) = Signal<[RecipeSwipingCardVM], NoError>.pipe()

    func fillSwipingQueueWith(recipeSwipingCards: [RecipeSwipingCardVM]) {
        // function implementation

        callObserver.sendNext(recipeSwipingCards)
    }
}

self.viewModel.callSignal.observeNext { recipeSwipingCards in
    print("method call")
}
```